# How do I return a result in a file finding function (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, return

Using Node.js, I'm trying to search in the current directory for a specific file with a random number appended at the end of the filename. After some searching online I found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find) would probably be best for the job, but I can't seem to make it work.

This is what I have so far:

```
const find = require('find');

function func1() {
    const x = find.file(/solution[0-9]*\.json/, __dirname, function(files) {
        console.log(files[0]);
        return files[0];
    });
    console.log(x);
}

func1();
```

This does a great job at finding the correct file and printing it to the console, but I still can't use the path to that file in func1, which is what I needed. This is the result I get:

```
{ error: [Function: error] }
C:\Users\dir1\dir2\solution78029853.json
```

I've tried multiple 'experimental' possible syntaxes but none of it seems to work and this is really the closest I can get. I did notice that the `{ error: [Function: error] }` is displayed before the `console.log(files[0]);`, but I'm not really sure if that's the problem and if it is, I don't know how I can prevent it. Without the `const x =` and the `console.log(x);` I get no error, and only the path is displayed, so I'm sure something with that is wrong; I just don't know what. I've been searching the web for over an hour now with no progress so hopefully someone knows what (probably simple) thing I've been doing wrong.

**Edit of func1() after Bergur's comment:**

```
function func1() {
    const x = find.file(/solution[0-9]*\.json/, __dirname, function(files) {
        console.log(files[0]);
        return files[0];
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            //
        }
    });
    console.log(x);
}
```

This doesn't produce the error, but just prints *undefined* instead for `console.log(x);`.

Comment: Have you tried to use .error to see what error you are getting?: getting:https://www.npmjs.com/package/find#errorcallback

Comment: I'm very much a newbie at JavaScript, which doesn't really help. I wasn't sure how to do this so I edited the question with the way I added it to my code...

Comment: no problem, we all had to start somewhere. Just console.log(err) inside that and hopefully it should show you something.

Comment: I believe you're running into this classic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `find.file` is asynchronous meaning that you will get the results in a callback (third argument of that function).
Assuming you are using ES6 and want to avoid the callback hell problem, you could use async and await like this:

```
const find = require('find');

async function findFile(name, path) {
  return new Promise(function (ok, fail) {
    find.file(name, path, function(files) {
        ok(files.find(_ => true)) // resolve promise and return the first element
    });
  });
}

async function func1() {
    const x = await findFile(/testFile[0-9]/, "files")
    console.log(`Path to my file: ${x}`);
}

func1();
```

Link: https://repl.it/repls/ZestyJauntyApplicationserver

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(x)` is not inside the `func1()` function

If you want to check the value of x, add a return statement inside the `func1` function then `console.log(func1())`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I edited the question so it now correctly represents the code I have so far. In the actual code however, `console.log(x)` is inside the `func1()` function so this should also work to check the value of x... (right?)

Answer (score 0):

This works 100%

```
//Try this
const util = require('util'); //https://nodejs.org/api/util.html
const findFileAsync = util.promisify(find.file);
const func1 = async () => {
  try{
    const results = await findFileAsync(/solution[0-9]*\.json/, __dirname);
    console.log(results[0]);
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}
func1();
```

Comment: I went with the other answer since that was more similar to the code I already had, but thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Don’t forget to use try/catch block in async functions.